# C#: Sort/OrderBy Enum Value

Tags: c#, linq

I have an IEnumerable that I've materialized from Linq2Sql.  I've already filtered out the records I want, now I want to order them based on a selected enum:

```
public enum Sort
{
  Time,
  Name,
  Value
}

public class LinqClass
{
   public DateTime Time;
   public string Name;
   public double Value;
}

Sort sort = Sort.Time
items.OrderBy(sort);
```

What is the best way to do this?  I could create an overloaded OrderBy(Sort s) that is just a big switch statement:

```
switch(sort)
  case Time:
    return this.OrderBy(x=>x.Time);
```

I could probably do something with a dictionary too.  Any other ideas, or is there a standard pattern for doing this.

Comment: Tbh the switch is fine. Anything else will be harder to maintain.

Comment: As a case passing a custom Comparer and built in `List.Sort()` method, this much heavy solution but much flexible and clean as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A switch statement is probably the best approach, as it makes it easy to spot when an invalid value has been passed.

You *could* use a `Dictionary<Sort, Func<IEnumerable<LinqClass>, IEnumerable<LinqClass>>>` but I don't think it would be worth it.

Comment: Alright, thanks.  Is there a slick way to do this without creating an extension method OrderBy(this IEnumerable<T> e, Sort s)?  I suppose you could do items.OrderBy(x=>x.SortRating(sort)) where SortRating returns like a double.  Not sure thats better though.

Comment: @Mark: No, because each ordering would return a different type... so you'd have a different type argument to `OrderBy`.

Answer (score 1):

If you realise the data as a `List`, you could use the `Sort` method that takes a `Comparison` delegate, and choose the comparison from a dictionary:

```
var comparisons = new Dictionary<Sort, Func<LinqClass, LinqClass, int>();
sorting.Add(Sort.Time, (x, y) => x.Time.CompareTo(y.Time));
sorting.Add(Sort.Name, (x, y) => x.Name.ComapreTo(y.Name));
sorting.Add(Sort.Value, (x, y) => x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value));

items.Sort(comparisons[sort]);
```