# Order query Results by Enum Name

Tags: c#, linq, enums

I have a `List<string>` with the following entries:

> "Summer", "Spring", "Winter"

I'd like to write a .OrderBy() that orders them based on this:

```
public enum Term {
    Spring = 0, Summer, Fall, Winter, All
}
```

Thus, the result I'd like to see is:

"Spring", "Summer", "Winter"

EDIT - For clarification, not every client has ALL of the available terms, but I just want consistency in the sorting of the list.

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780834/c-sort-orderby-enum-value

Comment: Do you really want "Fall" to come before "Spring"?

Comment: Nah, this isn't homework.  I'm trying to get these to properly display on a site settings page for configuration for clients.  I'll post what I've tried above.

Comment: @JonSkeet -- What I want to be sure of is that the order of the strings in the list is the same as the order of the Terms in the enum.  I'm grouping graduation terms for each year and then displaying them in columns in an HTML table.

Comment: @AdamLevitt: Right. So that's not ordering by name, it's ordering by *value*. Are you *really* just ordering the strings themselves? Not data related to them?

Comment: @JonSkeet -- Well I want to display the names as Column headers on the page, but order by the value that's mapped to the string name of the enum.  I wasn't sure if that was possible.

Comment: I think if you gave more details about what you're trying to achieve, you'd get more useful answers. For example, there's not much point in ordering just the *headings* if you then need to order the data as well, separately.

Comment: The below answers were very helpful.  Thank you all for the fast responses!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var q = l.OrderBy (x => Enum.Parse(typeof(Term), x));
```

Comment: @AdamLevitt, this appears to the be the most concise and correct solution. Did it work for you? If so, please mark it as the answer for both the community **and** the contributor.

Comment: This definitely did work.  Waiting for the site to allow me to accept it!

Answer (score 3):

```
List<string> terms = new List<string> { "Summer", "Spring", "Winter" };

var enumNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Term))
                    .OrderBy(s=>Enum.Parse(typeof(Term),s))
                    .ToList();

var orderedList = terms.OrderBy(s => enumNames.IndexOf(s)).ToList();
```

Comment: This will only work if the enums use default values. If, for example, Spring was 1 instead of 0, this method would fail.

Comment: Thank you very much... this definitely worked.  I'm going to also test the second answer strictly for brevity's sake.  Thanks!